# Drawing Hasse diagrams in R

Tags: r

Is there a package for R that handles binary relations (compute closures etc.) and draws the Hasse diagram of a relation?

Comment: Questions on Cross Validated (stats.SE) are expected to relate to statistics within the scope defined in the FAQ. This is a question about R and doesn't obviously relate to statistics. It would appear to belong on stackoverflow with the "r" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hasse()` function in the `DAKS` package may do what you need.

Hint: [Rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/) is an R specific search machine which works wonders. The function above was the very first hit.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, also for the Rseek.org reference!

Answer (score 4):

The DAKS package is one way to do it. You can read the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DAKS/vignettes/DAKS.pdf) here.

Hope that gets you started.